# routing Codeigniter with HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure, codeigniter-datamapper, codeigniter-routing

I'm using Codeigniter in combination with Datamapper and HMVC. see folder structure:

```
-application
   -controllers
      -admin
         -admin.php       
   -modules
      -users
        -models
        -controllers
        -views
```

Now i want to call my admin controller but the functions within this controller are not found only the index. my module controllers are routing correctly. suggestions?

Comment: how are you calling your functions in the url?, can you show the admin controller?

Answer (score 0):

If `admin/` was a module, you would be able to access this with `/admin/method` but since it's in the regular controllers directory, you would need to go to `admin/admin/method`. You can specify a default controller for a sub-directory inside the controllers directory, but it will only call the index method if no parameters are passed.